# Measure the column width of a table

Tags: tables, boxes

Is there a way to determine the width of the first column in a `tabular` enviroment?

I've thought about using a `savebox` but that would only give me the size of the text (and in one cell only), not the actual column width.

Or should I use `longtable` (or another package) to do that?

Comment: Might be an idea to tell us what you are trying to do. Then we can figure out a good solution.

Comment: yes, tell us a higher level picture. maybe you don't even need the size of the column.

Comment: Related question: [tables - How to get the row height and column width within a tabular? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590362/how-to-get-the-row-height-and-column-width-within-a-tabular). Contains solutions that use zref-savepos which allows obtaining the width within the cell itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has some limitations on the `tabular`: you can't have `\multicolumn` in the last row, nor optional arguments to `\\` (this one may be lifted off).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{mtabular}[3][c]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\multicolumn}[3]{\multispan{##1}##3}%
  \let\\\cr
  \setbox\tw@=\vbox{%
    \ialign{&##\unskip\hfil\cr\BODY\crcr}%
    \get@widths{#3}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}\BODY\end{tabular}}

\def\get@widths#1{%
  \def\@temp{\else\@latex@warning{No such column}\fi}
  \setbox\z@=\lastbox
  \get@next@width
  \xdef#1##1{%
    \noexpand\ifcase##1\relax\unexpanded\expandafter{\@temp}%
  }%
}
\def\get@next@width{%
  \setbox\z@=\hbox{\unhbox\z@\unskip\global\setbox\@ne=\lastbox}%
  \ifvoid\@ne
  \else
    \edef\@temp{\noexpand\or\the\wd\@ne\unexpanded\expandafter{\@temp}}%
    \expandafter\get@next@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mtabular}{lcr}{\foo}
abc & def & ghi \\
ABC & \multicolumn{2}{c}{aaa} \\
1 & 12 & 123
\end{mtabular}

The width of the first column was \foo{1}

The width of the second column was \foo{2}

The width of the third column was \foo{3}

\end{document}
```

It works by first typesetting the table in a “reduced” form, then taking off its last row and dismantling it bit by bit. The last argument to `mtabular` is a macro name that can later be used with a numeric argument for getting the relative column width.

[image]

Comment: +1 and accepted, thanks. But shouldn't there be `%` at the end of the line before `\endgroup`. I think this might cause some unwanted spacing.

Comment: @SándorKazi Yes, there should be. Still, an use example would be better, to clarify your aims.

Comment: I was just curious if it was possible. Here's what made me curious: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152784/36821 I've constructed an answer for this question based on your solution for this one.

Comment: Will this also work for longtable?

Comment: @Niranjan No: `longtable` doesn't build all the table in one swoop and uses multiple runs of LaTeX to stabilize the column widths.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\z#1{\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\tpos#1{\the\pdflastxpos}}}%
\def\foo#1#2{\ifcsname tpos#1\endcsname\the\dimexpr\csname tpos#2\endcsname sp -\dimexpr\csname tpos#1\endcsname sp\relax\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{!{\z{a}}l!{\z{b}}c!{\z{c}}r!{\z{d}}}
abc & def & ghi \\
ABC & \multicolumn{2}{c}{aaa} \\
1 & 12 & 123
\end{tabular}

The width of the first column was \foo{a}{b}

The width of the second column was \foo{b}{c}

The width of the third column was \foo{c}{d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Slightly different result than egreg, as the code takes a different view of whether tabcolsep padding is included or not.

Comment: +1, great, but egreg's answer is a little more generic (You have to actually print to table to use this, so it can't effect the the actual table. Or am I mistaken?)

Comment: @SándorKazi You can use the lengths within the table, latex will sort itself out on the next run.