# Texture or image as background for a single table cell

Tags: tables, backgrounds, cell

I want to add a image as background of a single cell of a table, such that the background image is scaled to the actual size of the cell. However, I could not figure out how to do it. I tried using tcolorbox and minipages, but both without success.

Something like in the following example would be perfect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text before.

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
    4 & \AddCellBackground{image} 5 & 6 \\\hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
Some more text after the table.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! For solid colour backgrounds you can use the `colortbl` package.

Comment: Yes, but what about non-solid background colors? E.g. hatched backgrounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, where the width of the table cell is given by the static width of a `p`-column you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{picture}
\newcommand*\AddCellBackground[4][\tabcolsep]{%
  \unskip\begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-#1,-\dp\strutbox){\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr
      #2+\dimexpr #1*2\relax\relax,height=#3]{#4}}%
  \end{picture}\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
Some text before.

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
  4 & \AddCellBackground{2cm}{\baselineskip}{example-image} 5 & 6 \\\hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
Some more text after the table.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the contents of the cell will also become an argument of `\AddCellBackground` several additional formatting could be done, e.g., for centering the cell contents. But in this case you also could use a new column type `B` (for *background*):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{B}[4]{%
  >{%
    \RaggedRight
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-#2\relax){\hskip-\tabcolsep\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr
        #1+2\tabcolsep\relax,height=#2]{#3}}%
    \end{picture}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}#4\strut\ignorespaces
    }%
    p{#1}%
  <{\unskip\strut\end{minipage}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
  4 &
      \multicolumn{1}{B{2cm}{3\baselineskip}{example-image}{\RaggedRight}|}{some
      more than one word} & 6 \\\hline
   4 & \multicolumn{1}{B{2cm}{3\baselineskip}{example-image}{\Centering}|}{some
       more than one word} & 6 \\\hline
   4 &
       \multicolumn{1}{B{2cm}{3\baselineskip}{example-image}{\RaggedLeft}|}{some
       more than one word} & 6 \\\hline
   7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: multiline example with different alignment]

But if the cell width is not given by a static value, you would have to measure out the widest cell of the column (e.g. using `\settowidth`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that can cope with multi-line cell contents. I used `tikz` `overlay` to put the picture in the background. The rest is scaling. I have assumed a fixed width of the cell, e.g. `p{2cm}`. If it is variable ther are some ways to find the width at [Measure the column width of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152813/measure-the-column-width-of-a-table), but it becomes more complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\AddCellBackground[3]{% {width}{image}{contents}
  \sbox0{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{#1}}\hline
      #3
    \end{tabular}}
  \tikz[overlay]{\node at (-\tabcolsep+0.5\wd0,-0.5\dp0+0.5\ht0-0.5\fboxrule){%
      \includegraphics[width=\wd0,height=\ht0+\dp0-0.5\fboxrule]{#2}};}%
  #3}

\begin{document}
Some text before.

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
    4 & 5 & \AddCellBackground{3cm}{example-image}{A longer cell contents that needs more space} \\\hline
    4 & \AddCellBackground{2cm}{example-image}{5} & 6 \\\hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

Some more text after the table.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If the cell contents should be centered it is best to define a new column type with the `array` package. Then a centered version of the `\addCellBackground` can be done:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\AddCellBackgroundCenter[3]{% {width}{image}{contents}
  \sbox0{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{C{#1}}\hline
      #3
    \end{tabular}}
  \sbox1{#3}
  \tikz[overlay]{\node at (0.5\wd1,-0.5\dp0+0.5\ht0-0.5\fboxrule){%
      \includegraphics[width=\wd0,height=\ht0+\dp0-0.5\fboxrule]{#2}};}%
  #3}
```

Here the image is inserted just before the text so the width of the actual text also comes into play. That means that this version does not work for multi-row cell content. The table with centered cells become (where the two first columns are centered and the last left aligned):

```
\begin{tabular}{|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
    4 & 5 & \AddCellBackground{3cm}{example-image}{6} \\\hline
    4 & \AddCellBackgroundCenter{2cm}{example-image}{5} & 6 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution almost works, but in the case if the content is centered using \AddCellBackground{2cm}{example-image}{\centering 5} it is not working anymore. Any solutions?

Comment: @W.Alpha I have added a version for centered cells. The centering should not be done using `\centering`, it is better to define a new column type with the `array` package.

Comment: This works only, if the cell with the background is the highest cell in that table row. This is the reason I've not used measuring for the cell contents but a parameters for the width *and* the height in my answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, That makes it a bit more complicated. To say the least.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, I could not figure out how to use your solution with multi-row or centered cell content. I would be glad to have a solution supporting both.

Comment: @W.Alpha The example in your question does not show multi-row neither centered cell contents.

Comment: @W.Alpha If you want to comment my answer, please add the comment below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Below uses matrix of nodes to create table instead of tabular environment.**

Here is another way using tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    Some text before. 

    \tikzset{ 
        table/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle,
                draw=black,
                align=center
            },
            nodes in empty cells,
            %%
            column 2/.style = {
                nodes={minimum width = 5em},
            },
        }
    }


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [table]{
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\};
    \node[minimum width=5em, fill overzoom image=redblock] at (m-2-2){5};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Some more text after the table.
\end{document}
```

[image: table with one cell filled with image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can easily fill any zone of merged cells (that is to say any `\Block`) with one of the patterns provided by Tikz.

You can also fill the `\Block` with an image. In the following example, the image has been provided by the package `mwe` but it's possible to use a image which would be more 'pattern-like'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{mwe} % for the image "example-image"

\tikzset
  {
    image/.style =
     {
       path picture =
         { \node at (path picture bounding box.center) { \includegraphics{#1} } ; } 
     }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
one     & two        & three & four   \\
five    & \Block[tikz={pattern=fivepointed stars}]{2-2}{} &     & six   \\
seven &               &     & nine
\end{NiceTabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
one     & two        & three & four   \\
five    & \Block[tikz={image=example-image}]{2-2}{} &     & six   \\
seven &               &     & nine
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]