# alternative to colortbl needed

Tags: color

due to the help of Ulrike in my question [How to get long captions across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402608/how-to-get-long-captions-across-pages/) I can now finally use extra long captions for my theses. Thanks again :-) The following code block is used for this for each picture:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{largeImage}
\end{figure}
\bigskip
\setbox0\vbox{\makeatletter
\let\caption@rule\relax
\captionof{figure}[short caption]{\kant[1-4]}
\global\skip1\lastskip\unskip
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}
\unvbox0
\setbox0\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
\global\setbox1\lastbox}
\unvbox1
\vskip\skip1
```

I need to use colored table rows in my thesis. As soon as I include the colortbl package with \include{colortbl} which is kind of best practice for that demand, my long text captions are always moved to the next page and I do not know why. Even if I don't use a command shipped with colortbl, the caption is simply moved to the next page instead of continuing there, here is the comparison.

with `\usepackage{colortbl}`:

[image: With using \usepackage{colortbl} the page layout looks like this. Unfortunately the caption is completely moved to the next page which causes loss of space]

without `\usepackage{colortbl}`:

[image: Without using \usepackage{colortbl} the page layout looks like this. Everything is nice, the long caption is completely moved to the next page which causes loss of space]

So, something strange happens when loading the package colortbl...

-> Is there an alternative to colortbl in order to have some background colors behind rows? I just found the idea to put a colored image in the background but that only applies to single cells, not to multicolumn rows ([Texture or image as background for a single table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384737/texture-or-image-as-background-for-a-single-table-cell)).

-> Maybe something the package code itself can be changes / overridden in order to get rid of that issue (I don't have any idea why colors can have an impact to the page layout....) Although I am a Latex Beginner, I could try to have a look to the source code of the package but I cannot find the relevant file containing the actual package code (https://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl?lang=de)

Does anyone have an idea how to get colored table rows in combination with the long-captions fix from [How to get long captions across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402608/how-to-get-long-captions-across-pages/)

As requested, here is the MWE. As soon as you uncomment the `\usepackage{colortbl}` package the caption gets moved to the next page as already mentioned in [How to get figure caption to span multiple pages, without having to switch everything to capt-of?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399698/how-to-get-figure-caption-to-span-multiple-pages-without-having-to-switch-every/399702#399702) by Willy Adler:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,headsepline,parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{width=16cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lehead{\fontfamily{cmr}\textsc{Results}}
\rohead{\fontfamily{cmr}\textsc{Results}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nooneline]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[format=plain, font={small, singlespacing}, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{colortbl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[H]%
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\bigskip
\setbox0\vbox{\makeatletter
\let\caption@rule\relax
\captionof{figure}[short caption]{\kant[1-4]}
\global\skip1\lastskip\unskip
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}
\unvbox0
\setbox0\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
\global\setbox1\lastbox}
\unvbox1
\vskip\skip1

\kant[6-7]

\end{document}
```

kind regards,

Stephan

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you provided an example that showed the problem. (I assume you are not using `\include{colortbl}` ?

Comment: Maybe give a try at `colortab`?

Comment: Please have a look at https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: As Willi Adler already mentioned in a comment to your answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399702/2388 loading color breaks it (more precisely the special inserted by \reset@color).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't notice the comment but from the problem description that was always likely to be the cause, rather than colortbl.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, was my first bet too ;-)

Comment: Hey there,
thanks for the open discussion.
@Bernard: I have tried to user colortab but I couldn't use it for my case as it does not support multicolumn rows. or do you have an MWE here for that case?

Cheers, Stephan

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have added the MWE

cheers,

Stephan

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks for your comment as well, do you have an idea how to sove this in my case?

Comment: thanks you are again writing `\include{colortbl}` in the text not in the code! That is very confusing, `\include` is a latex command but can't be used with `colortbl`

Comment: sorry, \include was a pure typo of mine :-( of course I use \usepackage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is unrelated to `colortbl` it is the `color` package. You need to disable color for the same reason that the existing code disabled the caption rule: color whatsits, like rule nodes may not be removed once added.  This just adds `\let\normalcolor\relax`

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,headsepline,parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{width=16cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lehead{\fontfamily{cmr}\textsc{Results}}
\rohead{\fontfamily{cmr}\textsc{Results}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nooneline]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[format=plain, font={small, singlespacing}, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[H]%
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\bigskip
\setbox0\vbox{\makeatletter
\let\caption@rule\relax
\let\normalcolor\relax
\captionof{figure}[short caption]{\kant[1-4]}%
\global\skip1\lastskip\unskip
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}
\unvbox0
\setbox0\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
\global\setbox1\lastbox}
\unvbox1
\vskip\skip1

\kant[6-7]

\end{document}
```