# How to automatically calculate the width of a multicolumn in a table based on the combined widths of the columns that are merged

Tags: tables, multicolumn, automation

Let's assume that I have a table containing two `l` type columns that both contain rather short amounts of text. In one of the following rows I want to use a `\multicolumn` that merges both columns. I want it to automatically be as wide as both above mentioned columns together.

I can either achieve this using `\multicolumn{2}{p{<width>}}` and visually estimate the needed with. As can be seen from the following example, this is not very accurate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
Some text & some more text \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{4.2cm}|}{\lipsum[4]}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

To get a better result, I can use the `\widthof` command from the `calc` package in order to measure the widths of the widest entries in both columns and calculate the required width for the multicolumn based on that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
Some text & some more text \\ 
text      & a significantly longer line of text\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\widthof{Some text}+\widthof{a significantly longer line of text}+2\tabcolsep}|}{\lipsum[4]}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this requires to manually determine the widest entry and entering it twice in the table (once in the column and once in the `\widthof` command)  which makes this approach somewhat error-prone and not too flexible.

Being aware of the `tabularx` package that is somehow able to automatically calculate the required width that is needed to make a table as wide as a specified length, I wonder if there is a more automated solution than the above described ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proof of principle and all the conceptional work has been done by David Carlisle in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152842/121799). You need to run twice. I am sure some TeX Guru can write a nicer code, but this shows that it is doable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\cwidth}
\makeatletter% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152842/121799
\protected\def\z#1{\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\tpos#1{\the\pdflastxpos}}}%
\def\foo#1#2{\ifcsname tpos#1\endcsname\the\dimexpr\csname tpos#2\endcsname sp -\dimexpr\csname tpos#1\endcsname sp\relax\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\edef\numA{\foo{a}{c}}
\ifx\numA\empty
\typeout{rerun}
\else
\cwidth=\numA
\advance\cwidth by-2\tabcolsep
\fi

\begin{tabular}{|!{\z{a}}l!{\z{b}}l!{\z{c}}|}
some text & some more text \\ 
text      & a significantly longer line of text\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\cwidth}|}{\lipsum[1]}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's easy peasy with `tblr` environment in LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\SetTblrInner{hspan=minimal}
\begin{tblr}{|l|l|}
\hline
 Some text & some more text \\
\hline
 \SetCell[c=2]{l} \lipsum[4] & \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only using one column and splitting the first row manually will avoid this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}|}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Some text & some more text\\
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\lipsum[4]\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that definitely contains an interesting idea. However, this still requires to manually determine the width of the `p` type column. As you can see, the text still does not line up perfectly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btUeY.png

Comment: If you add more text to the inner tabular, you'll find out, that the first line will be to wide.