# How to refer to the table width?

Tags: tables, width

I have a `tabular` or `longtable` table and sometimes need to refer to the table width. For example, I would like to add a `multicolumn` with a fixed width to allow for line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Col1 & Col2 \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{TABLEWIDTH}}{Some text longer than both columns.}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a "variable" that stores the table width?

Comment: From another way, you can first store the "TABLEWIDTH" in a length, then use it in multiple places.

Comment: Your question seems to be quite similar to the following one I asked a while ago: [How to automatically calculate the width of a multicolumn in a table based on the combined widths of the columns that are merged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498995/134144)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable