# Is a p-column allowed in a \multicolumn?

Tags: multicolumn

As far as I understood how tabulars are build, you declare how many columns you need and how to format them.  In some columns (notably `l`, `c` and `r`) LaTeX computes the needed width of those columns.  On other columns the author defines the width (by using `p{<width>}` and similar declarations).  LaTeX also adds intercolumn space.  This results in the total width of the table.

I also think, I understand, how LaTeX computes the resulting width of a `X` column, when used in a `tabularx` environment, fitting the column, so that the total width reaches the defined width of the table.

My question is: is it allowed, to use a `p{<width>}` declaration within a `\multicolumn`-command?  As far as I understand, LaTeX must get confused if the author inserts such a `\multicolumn`, which defines its own width, instead of using the LaTeX computed width of the combined columns in question.

For example's sake: lets say, we have two columns like a `l`-column and a `p{2cm}`.  LaTeX found out, that the longest entry in the first column is 1cm so, the total usable width of these two columns is `1 cm + 2\tabcolsep + 2cm`.  Suppose now that the author orders `\multicolumn{2}{p{5cm}}{...}`, which is obviously much wider than the LaTeX-computed width of `3cm + 2\tabcolsep`.

But what should authors use instead, if they want to be able to insert lots of text, being distributed into several lines as in a regular `p`-column?

Comment: yes it is allowed

Comment: As `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
text & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{text} \\
text & text & text \\
\end{tabular}\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
text & \multicolumn{2}{|p{6cm}|}{multicolumn text multicolumn text } \\
text & text & text \\
\end{tabular}\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
text & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.25cm}|}{\hspace{0pt}multicolumn text multicolumn text } \\
text & text & text \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` shows, using a `p` type column in a `\multicolumn` command definitely works.

Comment: How to determine the required width forr such a `p` type column is a different problem, about which I asked the following question [How to automatically calculate the width of a multicolumn in a table based on the combined widths of the columns that are merged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498995/134144). You may be interested in the answers to this, as well.

Comment: Note that when the multicolumn is wider than the combined columns, the excess width is added to the last column replaced.  Narrower is not a problem, although putting a \parbox inside a c column might look better.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you.  Short but unambiguous answer :-)

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for your examples.  My search haven't found them. :-(

Comment: @JohnKormylo using a parbox might help, as long, as you know how wide the box may be.  Another solution for this kind of problem would be a tabular in a tabular?!

Comment: As @leandriis pointed out: my question is kind of duplicate of his question and might hence be closed.  That would somehow add an answer it.

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray`, you can choose the width of the multicolumn cell and also the spanning algorithm:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}  
In Table \ref{tab:default} (default span), the multicolumn cell is 5cm wide. The third single cell is enlarged to reach, together with the other two cells, the total width of 5cm.  
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{\label{tab:default}Default span}
  \begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines,
    cell{1}{1}={c=3}{c,5cm}
    }
    Multicolumn cell with default span \\
    First & Second & Third \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

In Table \ref{tab:even} (even span), the multicolumn cell is 5cm wide. The three single cells are enlarged to have the same width and reach, all together, the total width of 5cm.  
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{\label{tab:even}Even span}
  \begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines, 
    hspan=even,
    cell{1}{1}={c=3}{c,5cm}
    }
    Multicolumn cell with even span\\
    First & Second & Third \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

In Table \ref{tab:minimal} (minimal span), the multicolumn cell is adapted to the total width of the three single cells. In this case, the 5cm width of the multicolumn cell is ignored.  
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{\label{tab:minimal}Minimal span}
  \begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines, 
    cell{1}{1}={c=3}{c,5cm},
    hspan=minimal,
    }
    Multicolumn cell with minimal span\\
    First & Second & Third\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: the vertical rules are added only to show the column width. They should not be used in professional tables.