# Get width of a c/l/r type column

Tags: tables

When I typeset some tabular or array in the following way :

```
begin{tabular}{c}
a \\
ab \\
abc \\
\end{tabular}
```

the width of the column adjusts to the maximum cell width. For example, assuming all letters a, b, c are 5mm wide, the width of the column will be 15mm (ignoring extra `\tabcolsep`).

I guess the tabular environment keeps the max width encountered until then. For example,

- when treating the first cell, `max_width` would be 0
- when treating the second cell, `max_width` would be 5mm (width of the first cell)
- when treating the third cell, `max_width` would be 10mm
- at the end, `max_width` would be 15mm, the actual width

Is there a way to get this max_width at some point in the tabular so that I can do stuff with it ?

```
begin{tabular}{c}
a \\
ab \\
abc \\
\doSomethingWithMaxWidth \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Probably some background infor on what exactly you want to do with the width afterwards would be helpful.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152838/134144 could be related

Comment: I'm trying to fix an issue in my custom package for typesetting variations tables. To put it simply, when my cells are : c \\ | \\ a | b, the |s must be aligned with the c, so I centered the column. But sometimes, a is empty and the cells are c \\ | \\ | b. If I center the column, an unwanted space is needed at the left of the second | to balance, so I change it to a l column, but I need to add some space before the |s to align, depending on the width of c. Thanks for the link, seems related indeed.

Comment: Probably one of the following two suggestions could alos hlep you with your task:`\begin{tabular}{c}
c \\ 
| \\ 
\phantom{a} | b
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l|r}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{c} \\ 
& \\ 
a & b
\end{tabular}`

Comment: The first doesn't fix the unwanted space at left (the ```\hphantom```). The 2nd is interesting but the c is not centered. I'm thinking about it, thanks !